# How can I write a file with containing a lua table using sol2

Tags: c++, lua

I've settled on using lua as my config management for my programs after seeing posts like [this](https://eliasdaler.wordpress.com/2015/08/10/using-lua-and-cpp-in-practice/) and loving the syntax, and [sol2](https://github.com/ThePhD/sol2) recently got released so I'm using that.

So my question is, how can I grab all the variables in my lua state and spit them out in a file?

say,

```
sol::state lua;
lua["foo"]["bar"] = 2;
lua["foo"]["foobar"] = lua.create_table();
```

would, in turn, eventually spit out

```
foo = {
    bar = 2
    foobar = {}
}
```

Is this at all possible and if so, how?

Comment: `foo = {bar = 2, foobar = {}}` notice the comma.

Comment: You need a table serializator. There are many scripts that do that in Lua's Wiki http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [this serializer](https://github.com/pkulchenko/serpent/blob/master/src/serpent.lua) to serialize my table and print it out, really quite easy!

This is what I came up with

```
std::string save_table(const std::string& table_name, sol::state& lua)
{
    auto table = lua["serpent"];
    if (!table.valid()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Serpent not loaded!");
    }
    if (!lua[table_name].valid()) {
        throw std::runtime_error(table_name + " doesn't exist!");
    }
    std::stringstream out;
    out << table_name << " = ";
    sol::function block = table["block"];
    std::string cont = block(lua[table_name]);
    out << cont;
    return std::move(out.str());
}
```